# Heroku: Why so many database connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, puma

I'm working on a rails project to act as a server and backend database for an iPhone app. In my attempts to do load testing I started getting errors saying there were too many db:connections and when I checked with pg:info I saw that to be true (Connections:        160/120).

This made some sense to me during the test but after it's over it still shows that many open connections which really confuses me. My questions

1) Why are these db connections remaining open after the process is done running?

2) Is it something in my configuration that's causing this?

```
rails: 4.2.4
Postgres: 9.4.4
Heroku dynos: five 1x-dynos
Web Server: Puma
Puma Workers: 2
Puma Threads: 9
Database Pool: ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 6 (so probably also 9 as MAX_THREADS is set to that)
```

3) Is there some way I can set the connections to close after the process is finished running?

This is my first time trying to design something to scale so sorry if this is basic as hell and let me know if there's anything I forgot to include.

puma.rb

```
 workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
 threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 6)
 threads threads_count, threads_count

 preload_app!

 rackup      DefaultRackup
 port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
 environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development

 on_worker_boot do
   # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
   # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rail-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
 end
```

Comment: Can you share your `puma.rb` file? Does your Heroku configuration have a separate value for `DB_POOL` set? Do you have any worker processes, i.e. Sidekiq or Rescue, running? Check `heroku ps` to see if you have any dynos you don't expect hanging around.

Comment: @RobertNubel posted puma.rb file above. ENV["DB_POOL"] doesn't seem to be defined in heroku and no worker processes besides Scheduler. Just added reaper to my database.yml but it doesn't look to be doing anything

Comment: Thanks. That all sounds good. Let's see if we can isolate the problem. If you scale down to just one dyno and reboot everything, how many connections are open on your database?

Comment: After dropping down to one 1x-dyno connections are reduced to 3/120. I should mention that when I was seeing the highest database connections I was testing on a relatively heavy load (30 hits/second over a minute), but even after the test was finished the number of connections wouldn't decrease without a server restart.

Comment: If you hit that one dyno with some load testing, do the connections go up?

Comment: Yes but much more marginally (1 hit/second over a minute increased it to 7/120)

Comment: I seem to have had some success with [PgBouncer](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer). It seemed before that connections were being left open for future use, but when a thread came looking for a connection to the database, ActiveRecord would just spawn a new connection instead. After putting PgBouncer in it looks like connections are actually being reused. As it stands it won't go below 27 connections even after a server restart but also hasn't gone over 38 even under heavy load (10 dynos, 2 puma workers, 8 threads and 30 hits/second). No idea why it's settling there.

Comment: I'm not clear on why Rails was ignoring your database pool size, but PgBouncer was going to be my recommendation if this couldn't be traced down to a specific reason. It's probably a good idea to have it in place regardless, if you expect high traffic.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to submit an answer I'll mark it as best. If not I'll just submit my own later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for awhile and trying several things (decreasing heroku dynos/puma workers/threads, enabling the rails ['reaper'](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool/Reaper.html), etc.), what ended up fixing my issue was [PgBouncer](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer).

Not too sure what was causing the underlying issue, but it looked like ActiveRecord/Postgres was leaving connections open for future use (expected behavior). However when a new process began running and requested a connection to the database, AR/PG would create a new connection instead of reusing the old (unexpected behavior). I could be wrong but that's how it appeared to me and PgBouncer seems to have taken care of that. Hopefully this helps anyone else with the same problem.